# Send Information inside a .png image then extract it through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, web-applications

After searching around in Google for a while I have not had any luck or guidance in my question.

**I want to be able to load up a website using javascript, ajax, in order to reduce the amount of requests needed by the server from the client.  My goal is to embed/encode data within an image such that only the client needs to request this image through ajax call, and then be decoded to find the js, css, and other files needed.  Then the js, css and other files will be inserted into the DOM.**

If I can get the above to work then I could have a lot of flexibility on how my webapp is loaded and be able to notify the user how close the webapp is to being ready for viewing.

**Currently my problem is that I cannot find how I would encode the data within an image.**

Even if this is not the way to be going about serving up a webapp my curiosity is getting the best of me and I would just really like to do this.

Any guidance or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

**Also: I am learning Python so if you know of a python module that I could play with that would be cool.  Currently i'm playing with the [pypng](https://github.com/drj11/pypng) module to see if this could be done.**

Comment: Meh. This is likely to cause more overhead (on client side for decoding, traffic because it breaks caching, etc.) than it saves requests. Just cache well, compress your JS and CSS, and put images into CSS sprites where possible. It's what the big boys do (for example, this very site) and it's the state of the art

Comment: Why use an image?  Why not use a single JavaScript file, or a JSON document?

Comment: So how does requesting the image in an AJAX call, vs. loading it natively in the browser REDUCE http requests?

Comment: While you can encode JS, CSS into PNG image and then decode it back I doubt that this is worth doing. Yes, compression rate will be high enough, however I'm not sure that it will beat GZIP. Plus the only way I can see is to decode it using canvas, which will not work in older IE versions.

Comment: I think if you will use an .png image then it self its size goes more than that you will consume without it..if you really want to workout on performance then it is better to take a look at these rules http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html or check stevesouders.com

Comment: Sometimes, the answer to the question "Why can't I find any information on this?" is "Because everyone else who tried concluded it wasn't worth the trouble."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be frank. Don't do that.

The brightest minds on earth use other methods to keep the number of requests and response time down. The most common technique for minimizing the number of requests is called Bundling. In short, you just copy'n paste all js files after each other into one big js file and all the css files into one big css file. This way you need to download two files, one js and one css. Better than that is usually not worth the trouble.

To further keep response times down you usually minify your js and css files. This is a process where all white space, comments, etc are removed and internal variable names are made as short as possible.

Finally you can serve both js and css files as gziped files to further reduce the file size to transfer.

There are many tools out there that does both bundling and minification for you. Google and pick one that suits your other tooling support.